# URI for client side version

Tags: rest, gwt, uri

Currently my system works on `abcd.appspot.com`, it has two buttons, one `Home` and other `About us`, clicking on each button displaying respective UI.

Requirement now is, if user writes `abcd.appspot.com/home` then it should display the 'home' page and `abcd.appspot.com/about` should display 'about us' page. I know if I chose the history token then it will be much more easier for me, but requirement is the it must be `abcd.appspot.com/{menu_id}/...` only.

In short, I want the REST URI for client side version. Any idea how it should be implemented in GWT? May be I am missing some simple clue.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment-identifier # is mandatory, if it is not present the page will reload...

You can remove the # using the HTML 5 feature "pushState", I known the last version of [errai](http://erraiframework.org/) can do this, see http://docs.jboss.org/errai/3.1.0-SNAPSHOT/errai/reference/html_single/#_pushstate_functionality, but this will work only with HTML5 compatible navigator...

A few others links about gwt and pushstate:

- https://github.com/jbarop/gwt-pushstate
- https://gist.github.com/tbroyer/1883821

Comment: I can understand how to use the "pushState" for url change, but now the question is, if user will copy and paste that url and fires in new window then how GWT app will understand which module to load or which screen to display? Do I have to write servlet filter to do it?